# Making inner table height 100% to parent td

Tags: html, css

I need to make inner table height to 100% height of parent td. 
Since I am using some angular ng-repeat with complicated data structure. I don't have option to change html structure.

Please help me with the solution how to set inner table to 100% height of parent td. I tried lot of options but didn't work.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.parent td,
.parent tr,
.parent th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.inner {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class='parent'>
  <tr>
    <th>head</th>
    <th>head</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>head</th>
          <th>head</th>
          <th>head</th>
          <th>head</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>values</td>
    <td>values</td>
    <td>Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes
      here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here, Description goes here,</td>
    <td>
      <table class='inner'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>H1 Val</td>
            <td>H2 Val</td>
            <td>H3 Val</td>
            <td>H4 Val</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the height of .parent also to 100% and that's it.

So;

```
    .parent{
      border:1px solid #000;
      border-collapse:collapse;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: its great. Thanks. one more help if we can solve.  when i make and made the border to inner table td . Its not touching to parent td. May be due to inner table, tbody,tr tags. how can we overcome.  find updated jsfiddle link.  

https://jsfiddle.net/bvsrao90/9xprmydj/1/

Comment: Remove the margin en padding's on the parent td. 
And add a 'border-spacing: 0px;' on the .inner table.